# WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0 - Failed to fetch. Possible Reasons: CORS Network Failure URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request issue

Tags: cors, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using `tryitout` tool of `devportal` in WSO2 API Manager `4.1.0` for [prototype API implementation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/prototype-api/create-mocked-js-api/)

OS: `Windows 11`.

Getting below ERROR in devportal:

[image: devportal ERROR]

Browser console:

[image: browser console]

CORS in publisher portal:

[image: CORS setting]

Reference:

[link 1](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/9314)

How can we resolve this ERROR?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening a new browser tab and invoke the URL https://localhost:8243/v3/1.0.6/pet/1.

You may receive a certificate error and try again the Try Out console in Dev Portal.

Comment: Hi @Joy Rathnayake,
Thanks for your response, I just recreated the same API again since it is running in my local and starts working, not sure what went wrong during initial attempt. i tried hit the same API in both tryit tool and postman and got response now. once again thanks for your time